# How to extract the high numeric values from data frame in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, extract

I am presenting a small data frame here that is from model output file and I extracted the required parameters `time` and `WatBlar` and converted it into data frame. 
Complete code starts from here.

```
library(stringr)

x <- readLines("G:/Rlearning/Mohsin-FM/Balance.out")

a <- grep("[T]", x, value = T)
b <- grep("Time", a , value = T)

c <-  b[-c(1,2)]
d <- grep("WatBalR", x, value = T)
```

The data is like that

```
data <- data.frame(time =c, watbalr = d)

> data


                         time                          watbalr
1  Time       [T]        3.0000  WatBalR  [%]              0.040
2  Time       [T]        6.0000  WatBalR  [%]              0.024
3  Time       [T]        9.0000  WatBalR  [%]              0.044
4  Time       [T]       30.0000  WatBalR  [%]              0.034
```

I checked the data class it is data frame that is shown below.

```
> c
[1] " Time       [T]        3.0000" " Time       [T]        6.0000"
[3] " Time       [T]        9.0000" " Time       [T]       30.0000"

> class(c)
[1] "character" 



> d
[1] " WatBalR  [%]              0.040" " WatBalR  [%]              0.024"
[3] " WatBalR  [%]              0.044" " WatBalR  [%]              0.034"

> class(d)
[1] "character"

> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
```

The code to extract the required values is written as shown below. But it is just assigning the value of the time 0 to 9, any value above than 9 it just start it again 0 to 9.

```
times   <- sub("^.+?(\\d)", "\\1", c)
WatBlaR <- sub("^.+?(\\d)", "\\1", d)

times   <- as.numeric(times)
WatBlaR <- as.numeric(WatBlaR)

# plot 
plot(x = times, y = WatBlaR)
```

The results for 4 values as mentioned above in data frame are shown below.

```
> times
[1] 3 6 9 0
```

But the required results for time are

```
3, 6, 9, 30
```

When I want to extract the model data from the daily basis data it present the values as

```
> times    
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

It just followed the sequence of all the time available 0 to 9, the required out should be like that

```
> times
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please confirm the types of the data.frame cols with `str(data)` and update your answer with that info.

Comment: > str(data)
'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time   : Factor w/ 4 levels " Time       [T]        3.0000",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ watbalr: Factor w/ 4 levels " WatBalR  [%]              0.024",..: 3 1 4 2

Comment: kindly checked the updated question, i provided the detail for easy understanding about data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the numbers using `sub` from the base package where you look for a pattern of the form

- any number of digits followed by
- a dot (optional) followed by
- any number of digits (optional)

This is how you could do it:

```
library(magrittr)   ## For pipe %>%

# Some sample data
data <- data.frame(time = c(" Time       [T]        3.0000", 
                " Time       [T]        6.0000",
                " Time       [T]        9.0000", 
                " Time       [T]       30.0000"),
        watbalr = c(" WatBalR  [%]              0.040", 
                " WatBalR  [%]              0.024", 
                " WatBalR  [%]              0.044", 
                " WatBalR  [%]              0.034"),    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Extract pattern and convert to numeric:
times <- sub("[^[:digit:]]*(\\d+\\.?\\d*).*", "\\1", data$time) %>%
        as.numeric
WatBalR  <- sub("[^[:digit:]]*(\\d+\\.?\\d*).*", "\\1", data$watbalr) %>%
        as.numeric

> times
# [1]  3  6  9 30
> WatBalR
# [1] 0.040 0.024 0.044 0.034
```

Comment: it is providing the exact values. but it is not plotting the graph. the error is like that when I want to plot. thnx for the time.  plot(x = times, y = WatBlaR)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  object 'WatBlaR' not found

Comment: R cannot find the variable. That's because in my code, the variable is called `WatBalR` not `WatBlaR`. You have to change that.

Comment: kindly can you look my this question "importing tables of different columns at specific position of the data frame and finally creating the text file in R"  I am trying to write the last file of my model input. then I will write a code in R that will read all R codes that I wrote and will run the model. thnx

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to extract values from a character vector in R. The base string functions are not as rich as might be desired for these kinds of situations. Consider adding `stringr` which is very handy for this kind of work.

```
library(stringr)

# I will create a toy df
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,16,5), B=c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8), C=c('3.0000  WatBalR', '3.0000  WatBalR', '12.0000  WatBalR', '6.0000  WatBalR'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# now I can extract with a simple regex pattern
times <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$C, '^[0-9]+'))
```

Here we use `str_extract` to extract with a signature of `(data on which to operate, regex pattern)`. We are also using `$` to name the column in the data.frame and make it more legible, so we can pass what we need.

I can also get the doubles easily:

```
watblar <- as.double(str_extract(df$B, '^[.0-9]+'))
```

and types are correct

```
> str(times)
 num [1:4] 3 3 12 6
> str(watblar)
 num [1:4] 0.1 0.4 0.6 0.8
```

Comment: install.packages("strings")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mohsin/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘strings’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
> library(strings)
Error in library(strings) : there is no package called ‘strings’

Comment: Sorry. Library is *stringr*

Comment: i also tried stringr. it is also part of my code. its not working